# Seeking Guidance on Camera Selection and Image Transfer for Drone-based Insulator Monitoring Project

Tags: fpv-cameras, camera, homemade-drone

We're working on a final year project involving a drone that flies to towers, captures images of insulators, and sends them for processing on a computer. We've assembled the drone, and now our main challenge is finding a suitable camera.

Unfortunately, in Pakistan, access to certain components can be a bit challenging. We're specifically looking for a camera that can act as an FPV (any quality is fine) and can trigger its shutter using an RC transmitter from the ground. The camera needs to have three key functions:

1. **Electronically Triggerable by RC Transmitter**
2. **FPV Functionality**
3. **Capability to Save Pictures in SD Card or Deliver to Raspberry Pi**

We're also wondering about the best way to transfer high-quality images back to the computer. One idea is using a Raspberry Pi to receive the images and then potentially using a special transmitter module for transmission.

Our goal is to set up a system where we can retrieve these images on our ground computer, which will have an AI interface model for monitoring the images once they're captured in good quality. We're exploring budget-friendly options that will be effective for our final year project. Any guidance on making the right decisions, especially regarding electronic triggers versus servo methods, would be greatly appreciated. We're aiming for choices that align with our budget constraints while ensuring the success of our project. Thanks in advance for any advice!

There are a few options like getting a camera system from a toy camera like e99 k3pro. And we have
Foxeer 30x Zoom 700TVL CMOS Camera PWM Control, however this option includes that I use a mini fpv DVR but thats only limited to rendering a video and not storing pictures.

But there are just so many questions i need answers to. If someone can help me, that would be so great!